# Developer Console checkpoint field results are mixed up

Tags: developer-console, checkpoint

In developer console, I've set a checkpoint and then I run a unit test.  When I view the checkpoint result for an sObject in the Symbols tab, some of the values are mixed up among the fields.  For example, a date field shows a "false" value, while an Id field shows a datetime, etc.

Has anyone seen this before?  This happens in Chrome on both Mac and Windows.